# How to test for intercept in a regression problem in R

Tags: r, regression

so for my question it asks me to test if the intercept for a linear regression model is greater than 9 in R. I'm not exactly sure how to do that. any ideas? I tried the t-test manual but it's not working for me.

Comment: You will need to paste in the question for context. In addition, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: The estimate of your regressor with features = zero(s) should give you the intercept term.

Answer (score 4):

The R output, of `summary(lm(y~x))`, gives a parameter estimate $b_{0}$ and a standard error se($b_{0}$) for the intercept.  The typical t-test (for $H_0: \beta_0 = 0$) is obtained by comparing $T = \frac{b_{0} - 0}{\text{se}(b_{0})}$ to a t-distribution with the number of degrees of freedom equal to the error degrees of freedom.  So, how would you modify the statistic $T$ when your hypothesis is $H_0: \beta_0 = 9$?